# Hiding a subview from another method

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, hidden, subview

Currently I'm using the following line to add a method's view as a subview to another view inside a method.

`[self.landscape addSubview:[self makeSpin]];`

This works well, and all is dandy, but now I need to know how to hide it.

Obviously `[self.landscape setHidden:[self makeSpin]];` doesn't do the trick.
Could anyone provide me with a quick sample on how to do this?  Or even a point in the right direction would help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the view that makeSpin returns is an instance variable (if not you somehow have to make it an instance variable or use tags). If it is, try this:

```
[self makeSpin].hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `[self makeSpin]` returns same object all the time (not creating and returning new view and not an auto released view) then you can remove the view like:

`[[self makeSpin] removeFromSuperView]`;

else you need to add a tag to the sub view (view returning from

```
[self makeSpin]).
```

Like:

```
UIView *tempView = [[self makeSpin] retain];
tempView.tag = 7;
[self.landscape addSubview:tempView];
[tempView release];
```

For removing the view you need to write like:

```
[[self.landscape viewWithTag:7] removeFromSuperview];
```

Also you can use this loop,

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.landscape subviews])
{
    if (subview.tag == 7)
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `makeSpin` returns an autoreleased view that isn't being assigned to an instance variable, then you're not going to have any access to it other than trying to find it in `self.landscape`'s subviews array.  By far the easiest thing to do here would be to create a property in your class and use it to hold the value of the new subview, so that you can play with it later.  You'll just have to remember to set it to nil in your viewDidUnload method.